# Trouble printing specific columns with pandas dataframes using .iloc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm creating a 4x4 dataframe with pandas and trying to print the last 2 columns with all row data using `print(df.iloc[:][2:])` however it is printing the last two rows and all columns - the same as `print(df.iloc[2:][:])`.  Am I misunderstanding how the console interprets the brackets and colons?

Here is the code I'm executing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12],
                  [13, 14, 15, 16]])
index = ['Worst', 'Index', 'Ever', 'Dude']
columns = ['Best', 'Columns', 'Today', 'Bro']
sick_df = pd.DataFrame(data = data1, index = index, columns = columns)

print(sick_df)
print('\n', sick_df.iloc[:][2:])
```

Here is the output from the above code:

```
       Best  Columns  Today  Bro
Worst     1        2      3    4
Index     5        6      7    8
Ever      9       10     11   12
Dude     13       14     15   16

       Best  Columns  Today  Bro
Ever     9       10     11   12
Dude    13       14     15   16
```

I was expecting the 2nd print method to display all four rows with the last two columns.  This output is what I expect to get from `print('\n', sick_df.iloc[2:][:])` and indeed when I change the 2nd print method to this line I get the same exact output.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,2:]`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of iloc and loc is [row index, col index]

```
sick_df.iloc[:, -2:]
```

The reason your code is returning a different result is due to chaining,

```
sick_df.iloc[:]
```

returns the entire dataframe. Now when you chain that with

```
sick_df.iloc[:][2:]
```

You get all the rows from index 2 till the end of the data frame.